# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

## Problem

Dear All,
I successfully connected my JAVA desktop application with MSSQL using JDBC. Now when i try to connect my Java Dynamic Web Application with (MSSQL using JDBC) using same method it will show the exception.

### Sql Exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ReamsDB;user=sa;password=xxx;
```

I try many solutions from internet but none helped me. Kindly help me to get rid of this problem.

Below all files are attached.

Thanks.

```
## DBTesting.Java ##
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager; 
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.*;
public class DBTesting {
        public  void establishConnection() throws SQLException  {
            
            
            String user = "sa";
            String pass = "ansari12345";    
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;" +
                       "databaseName=ReamsDB;user="+user+";password="+pass+";";
            Connection con = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String sql = "Select * From Basement";
                    
            try {
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                System.out.println("DB COnnected !");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                int ID = rs.getInt(1);
            String SquareFeetCount = rs.getString(1);
            String _FinishedPercent = rs.getString(1);
            int s_ID = rs.getInt(1); 
                        
            System.out.println("ID :"+ID+"  SquareFeetCount :"+SquareFeetCount+" FinishedPercent :"+_FinishedPercent);
                
            }
            con.close();
            
            }
```

}

```
## Hello.jsp ##
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="JDBCServletPath" method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the DriverManager code.`DriverManager.getConnection(String url)` invoke the following code:

**code from jdk1.7**

```
   private static Connection getConnection(
        String url, java.util.Properties info, Class<?> caller) throws SQLException {
        /*
         * When callerCl is null, we should check the application's
         * (which is invoking this class indirectly)
         * classloader, so that the JDBC driver class outside rt.jar
         * can be loaded from here.
         */
        ClassLoader callerCL = caller != null ? caller.getClassLoader() : null;
        synchronized (DriverManager.class) {
            // synchronize loading of the correct classloader.
            if (callerCL == null) {
                callerCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            }
        }

        if(url == null) {
            throw new SQLException("The url cannot be null", "08001");
        }

        println("DriverManager.getConnection(\"" + url + "\")");

        // Walk through the loaded registeredDrivers attempting to make a connection.
        // Remember the first exception that gets raised so we can reraise it.
        SQLException reason = null;

        for(DriverInfo aDriver : registeredDrivers) {
            // If the caller does not have permission to load the driver then
            // skip it.
            if(isDriverAllowed(aDriver.driver, callerCL)) {
                try {
                    println("    trying " + aDriver.driver.getClass().getName());
                    Connection con = aDriver.driver.connect(url, info);
                    if (con != null) {
                        // Success!
                        println("getConnection returning " + aDriver.driver.getClass().getName());
                        return (con);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    if (reason == null) {
                        reason = ex;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                println("    skipping: " + aDriver.getClass().getName());
            }

        }

        // if we got here nobody could connect.
        if (reason != null)    {
            println("getConnection failed: " + reason);
            throw reason;
        }

        println("getConnection: no suitable driver found for "+ url);
        throw new SQLException("No suitable driver found for "+ url, "08001");
    }
```

If the `registeredDrivers` doesn't contain DriverInfo of sqlserver driver(or url format error).The code will throw `SQLException("No suitable driver found for "+ url, "08001")`.

You can call `DriverManager.getDriver(String url)` to test whether contain the dirver.If yes,I think it is url format error. Otherwise,I think it is a lib issue.You can call `DriverManager.registerDriver(java.sql.Driver driver)` or try `Class.forName` before you call `DriverManager.getConnection`.
`Class.forName` can check lib. If you doesn't have the Class,it will throw `ClassNotFoundException`.

Variable `registeredDrivers` is initialized at `loadInitialDrivers` method.You can look at it for more useful information.

Hope these can help you

Comment: Yes i attached the same Jar file which i attached in my Java desktop project.

Comment: @ZephyrGuo this is not an answer. If you want any clarification, you should ask in comment instead.

Comment: do you load the dirver class? `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`this is a mysql sample, you class name is right?

Comment: no. Because in driver4 there is no need to explicitly call     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); That's why i didn't add this piece of code.

Comment: do you hava correct jar in you web server runtime lib?If you use Tomcat,you should cop jar into Tomcat lib.

Comment: Hi，@AbtisamAnsari  ,Apologizing to my bad answer before,I have updated.

Comment: Dear @ZephyrGuo what is meant by "More about initialization of registeredDrivers you can read loadInitialDrivers,it can help you to find why doesn't contain the driver" statement ?    Furthermore, i tried the above solutions. Thanks for help my friend.

Comment: I have updated the statement.Your issue looks like different runtime environment between the tow project.Even if the code is same.@AbtisamAnsari

Comment: Dear @ZephyrGuo if it possible that i can call u at skyp and share my screen with you. May be than you can help me to find the answer. my email :abtisamahmed92@gmail.com if you can help me via skp then please send me your skp id in my email. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I write a test code send to you email.I doubt your lib.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it will answer your question but for my part (not working on a local host): `DriverManager.getConnection` don't have 1 parametre but 3

like this : `String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://BCNSDBA042\\DEV_CP1_CI_AS";
            String user = "user";
            String passwd = "passwrd";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);`

your url should look like this `"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:5432/NAME`

hope it's help.